# Unable to recompile package in Oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle9i

I have a need to recompile a package in oracle 9i. But the session gets hung forever. When I checked in `V$SESSION_WAIT`, got to know that it is waiting on an event `'library cache pin'`. Couldn't get a possible solution for 9i version. Is there anyway to find the session, that is executing my package and kill it?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. 
To find what sessions run a code which contains a name:

```
select s.*,sa.*  
FROM v$session s 
left join v$sqlarea sa 
   on s.sql_address=sa.address AND s.sql_hash_value=sa.hash_value
where sql_text like '%your_package_name_here%';
```

After this, you have the pid and serial so you can kill the session you need to kill. (The code above may return sessions that you do not need to kill, for example, it is finding itself :)  )

Answer (score 0):

Oracle offers no built-in easy path to do this.

If your application uses the [DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_appinf.htm#CHECEIEB) routines to register module usage you're in luck: you can simply query V$SESSION filtering on MODULE and/or ACTION.  Alternatively, perhaps you have trace messages in your PL/SQL which you use?

Otherwise, you need to start trawling [V$SQLTEXT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_3065.htm#REFRN30260) (or another of the several views which show SQL) for calls containing the package name.  Remember to make the search case-insensitive.  This will give you a SQL_ID you can link to records in V$SESSION.

This will only work if your package is the primary object; that is, if it is the top of the call stack.  That is one explanation for why the package is locked for so long. But perhaps your package is called from some other package: in that case you might not get a hit in V$SQLTEXT.  So you will need to find the programs which call it, through [ALL_DEPENDENCIES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1066.htm#REFRN20053), and sift V$SQL_TEXT for them.

Yes, that does sound like a tedious job.  And that is why it is a good idea to include some form of trace in long-running PL/SQL calls.